ngx-quill stripping custom directive from HTML loaded from DB. How can I prevent this?
I am working with records in a database, these records come from user inputted data from from a tinyMCE text editor in an old angular JS app. They have the ability to reference images uploaded to the app using a custom directive under the hood. This will create a tags with a custom directive that look something like this:
<a custom-attachment-link="my-attachment">Attachment Name</a>
The issue I am running into is that every time this is loaded into my new app using ngx-quill the custom attribute is stripped. How can I whitelist this directive? I tried using custom blots but I am finding it hard to get that to work. I cannot use tineyMCE due to license pricing. Open to other suggestions that have a true MIT license. I am open to trying other editors (I have tried p-editor and ngx-editor so far and running into roughly the same issues).

can you try a way with data- attiribute, like data-custom-attachment-link? not sure how do you expect the directive to run. are you using something like $compile?
